# Redis keys deletion (aws elastic cache)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have used the below script to delete the Keys from my redis  node ( using AWS elastic cache service ) , `bytes used for cache` metrics dropped from 100 GB to 80 GB which is fine since we deleted around 1,60,000 keys. In a few minutes, bytes used for cache increased rapidly and hit the maximum (106GB). Is this because of the delete operation ?
any fault with the script?

In addition to above after reaching the 106 GB, in few minutes drastically it reduced again to 80 GB and stabilized

```
count=0
while read -r delkeys
do
        ((count=count+1))
    echo "KEYNAME:$delkeys"
        redis-cli -h $REDIS_HOST -p $REDIS_PORT DEL "$delkeys"
                if [[ $count == 1000 ]]
                then
                sleep 5
                count=0
                fi
done < filename
```

Engine Version : 2.8.21
Engine : Redis

In addition to the above part, on previous day I have taken values for all the 1,60,000 keys by using `LRANGE "$dumpkeys" 0 -1` in the above script  but havent faced any performance issue like cpu or high RAM utilisation

Comment: Just to confirm, you are saying you ran the script and it went from 100 GB to 80 GB to 106 GB then down to 80 GB again?

Comment: Actually after deleting the keys by using the above script my memory reduced from 100GB to 80 GB.  But few minutes later suddenly I could see the rapid growth from 80 GB to almost 106 GB . I just got worried whether the above script not efficient for deleting keys in redis.

Comment: An the interesting thing is after reaching 106 GB , within few minutes bytes used for cache came again to 80 GB and got stabilized